# C++ Chrono - How to use the duration_cast on std::atomic<long long>?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, c++-chrono, long-long

I'm have a `class Bar` with:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    //...
private:
    std::atomic<long long>          m_keepAlive;
}
```

This `class` have some methods described below.

This `method` gets the epoch in `ms`:

```
long long Bar::getTimeSinceEpoch()
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> p = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    const long long epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(p.time_since_epoch()).count();
    return epoch;
}
```

This `method` is being called from another `thread` and updates my `m_keepAlive`.

```
void Bar::keepAlive() //This method is being called from other thread
{
    m_keepAlive= getTimeSinceEpoch();
}
```

On my `Bar class`, I have a method that keeps calling this `checkKeepAlive()` method and checks if **2 seconds** has passed, since the last time `Bar::keepAlive()` was executed.

```
void Bar::checkKeepAlive()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

   //COMPILATION ERROR here
    auto difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - m_keepAlive); 

    auto timeMsSinceNoReply = difference.count();

    if(timeMsSinceNoReply >= 2000)
    {
        //timeout
    }
}
```

To acomplish this, I've created the  `std::atomic<long long>` to be **thread safe** on my class.

However, I get this compilation error:

```
no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >’ and ‘long long int’)
```

How can I use the `duration_cast` on `std::atomic<long long>`?

Comment: You're trying to subtract two incompatible types. You need to make sure that both are the same type. For example by casting or converting one of the involved variables to the same type as the other (it doesn't happen automatically).

Comment: That doesn't work with or without `atomic`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chrono library is build in order to keep you explicit and type safe, by using all the calls to `std::chrono::duration::count` you are *abusing* library.

`now - m_keepAlive` is illegal in your example. Your compiler tells you this.

- `now` is of type `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.
- `m_keepAlive` is of type `std::atomic<long long>`.

Even if you change `m_keepAlive` to `long long`, it will still not work.

You need to convert `m_keepAlive` to a duration, before you try to subtract it from `now`.

For instance: `std::chrono::milliseconds(m_keepAlive.load())` will interpret the value kept by `m_keepAlive` as a number of milliseconds.

Full expression should be:
`const auto difference = now - std::chrono::system_clock::time_point(std::chrono::milliseconds(m_keepAlive.load());`

Then use as follows:
`if(difference >= std::chrono::seconds(2)) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks @dalle the difference is correct, but the `if(difference >= std::chrono::seconds(2))` doesn't compile, due to the `no match for ‘operator>=’ (operand types are ‘const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >’ and ‘std::chrono::seconds {aka std::chrono::duration<long int>}’)` How can I compare this duration with a timepoint?

Comment: @waas1919 I forgot to initialize the `time_point` in the difference expression.

Comment: This is exacly what I need. Thanks!